# Connect two systems and route traffic

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Here's a scenario that I want to implement using C# or C++.

I want to connect PC-1 to PC-2 over internet and use PC-2 as the gateway for PC-1, so that all the outgoing and incoming traffic to PC-1 gets routed through PC-2. I know about using proxy servers and VPN. But I'd like to implement this on my own using 2 applications, preferably in .NET, that run on these 2 computers.

Edit: I need something similar to a VPN network, when I enable the program in PC-1 it should route entire traffic to PC-2 not just http traffic. I am not sure where to start with.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement a virtual network interface and should also edit the route table to make your network interface look like the shortest path to the target ip addresses but even this does not guarantee all the traffic to be sent from your network interface

Comment: could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Not now sorry, I am outside now. Read documentation for route tables. Your Windows system has one. It is a table containing destination ip addresses, (masked, I mean, you can specify zones), a network interface to use for that ip address, and the distance (it is not an actual value, but is significant because it is used to select the network interface to use when sending packets to that IP). Therefore, if you enter a record *.*.*.* with the shortest possible distance 1, you may expect all the traffic to go through your network interface

Comment: And IP address of PC2 will be the gateway of course

Comment: But as I said, having this does not guarantee that all the network traffic goes through your interface, because the network interface selection algorithm also looks for the most specific destination IP address record in the table. This means that, if there is a record for a specific IP address in the table, that network interface will probably be selected for transmission and it will not go through pc2

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787509(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I've read that link. As you said, it doesn't guarantee, is there any concrete solution just like how a VPN client works, except that I want the PC-2 to have synchronized with PC-1 to allow or disallow this routing.

Comment: Even with juniper Vpn client, you still have the option to connect to destinations outside the Vpn network, and you should have it. I don't want my Lync to disconnect because I started a vpn to one of our clients. Even you guarantee, people have the option to add a record to their route table to workaround

Comment: I know there are clients which does this. But I'd like to implement it myself and need a few pointers to start.

Comment: all you can do is port forwarding. unless you develop something in kernel level.

Comment: I'd like to develop it myself, and like to know few pointers on where to start with